# Pass Data back by using blocks instead of delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have been trying to pass data using blocks

sent data backward

declare block in your **secondViewController** .h file

```
@property (nonatomic, copy)void(^myBlock)(NSString *);
```

call block wherever you need to pass data from .m file of secondViewController

```
myBlock(@"this will displayed in firstViewController");
```

3.import above .h file in your firstViewController .m file and define your block as

```
secondViewController *ref =[[secondViewController alloc ]init];
 ref.myBlock =^void(NSString *data)
{
self.labelOffirstviewcontroller=data;
};
```

while run time I am getting EXC bad Access Error Can anyone sort the issue to this?

Comment: you have define closures in wrong manner. we do not define closure as property

Comment: then can u explain how to define it? @Wolverine

Comment: typealias ClosureType = (ParameterTypes) -> (ReturnType)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `[[secondViewController alloc ]init];` you are creating a new instance of the view controller so you can set the block on it, but then it isn't used and gets destroyed. You need to use `prepareForSegue` or similar depending on how you display the VC so you set the block on the correct instance.

VC2 should generally check if the block is nil before calling it too.

The property should also be strong, not copy. ARC does the right thing anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to pass data .

```
secondViewController *ref =[[secondViewController alloc ]init];
ref.myBlock =^void(NSString *data)
{
self.labelOffirstviewcontroller=data;
};
```

this code should be given where we push viewcontroller